# Javascript RegEx Mysteries (for a poor C programmer)

Tags: javascript, regex

This is clearly a RTFM issue, but after I did so repeatedly I just can't get the damn thing to work so there are times when asking for help makes sense:

```
   var text = "KEY:01 VAL:1.10,KEY:02 VAL:2.20,KEY:03 VAL:3.30";
   var pattern = '/KEY:(\S+) VAL:([^,]+)/g';
   //var pattern = '/KEY:(\S+) VAL:(.?+)(?:(?=,KEY:)|$)/g';
   //var pattern = '/KEY:(\S+) VAL:(.+)$/g';
   //pattern.compile(pattern);
   var kv = null;
   var row = 0, col = 0;
   while((kv = pattern.exec(text) != null))
   {
     row = kv[1].charAt(0) - '0';
     col = kv[1].charAt(1) - '0';
     e = document.getElementById('live').rows[row].cells;
     e[col].innerHTML = kv[2].slice(0, kv[2].indexOf(","));
   }
```

kv[1] is supposed to give "01" 
kv[2] is supposed to give "1.10"

...and of course kv[] should list all the values of 'text'
to fill the table called 'live'.

But I can't get to have `pattern.exec()` succeed in doing that.

Where is the glitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the delimiters for the RegExp should be `/`s, there's no need to put them in `'` delimiters.  i.e. to get your `exec` to run properly you should have:

```
var pattern = /KEY:(\S+) VAL:([^,]+)/g;
```

Second, you're assigning a boolean to `kv` which you don't want.  The while will obviously only evaluate to `true` if it's not `null` so that's redundant.  Instead you just need:

```
while (kv = pattern.exec(text)) {
```

That should get your code to work as you desire.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - you have made ny day!

Answer (score 2):

the syntax for pattern objects doesn't include quoting, such as:

```
var pattern=/KEY:(\S+) VAL:([^,]+)/g;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var pattern = /KEY:(\S+) VAL:([^,]+)/g;
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start with.